# Drupal Add Content Form - Where is the Code?

Tags: forms, drupal-7, nodes

I need to be able to access the code that Drupal uses to display the form for adding Content.  Really just need to access 1 node's code.  The problem is that a Node was added as content to be outputted within a view, however, the Node creation is Public, thus causing a form type of look and feel to it.  However, the Content Node Creation Form is now being Spammed.  I have implemented a Bot Blocking Script via HTML and CSS and JS that works wonderfully on previous sites (Non-Drupal related), but I don't know how I can implement the same code on Drupal.

I would need to access this Nodes HTML,CSS, and/or JS for the Form Creation in Drupal.

Any ideas where to start?

Or perhaps this would be inside the structure of the node?  Can you add uneditable HTML Code inside of a content node by default?  This is probably a dumb question tbh, but as some have said, the only dumb question is the one that's not asked.

Comment: Have a look at `function node_form()` in `node.pages.inc` under `module/node`. It's the starting point for node add/edit form generation. And for your issue, you may look at [Captcha module](https://drupal.org/project/captcha).

Comment: Nice, thank you, I'll look into it for sure.